# Add State at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create at animation controller for at object at run time and then add states within that controller.

For exmple, a state with animation for walking.

I have successfully create the state but I am unsure as to how to assign a motion clip to that state?

```
var rootStateMachine = controller.layers[0].stateMachine;
//add state
var stateA1 = rootStateMachine.AddState("stateA1");
```

I want to assign an animation clip to stateA1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores in the [AnimatorState.motion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorState-motion.html) property.

```
stateA1.motion = your_animation_clip;
```

Comment: And how exactly do I get my_animation_clip's reference in the script? What should be its type?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by first loading the animation clip and then assigning its value to motion variable.

AnimationClip clip = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Animations/Run_Spot.fbx", typeof(AnimationClip)) as AnimationClip;

stateA1.motion = clip;

Thanks for the help @shingo :)